# Splitting Fields, roots and quotient rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, quotient-spaces

With a lot of free time on my hands, I've been looking at bits of abstract algebra I never studied as a student (25+ years ago).  I think I'm getting to grips with the ideas of rings, ideals and splitting fields, but in modifying a  problem I've seen, I've come across a phenomenon I don't understand.  I'd appreciate if someone could explain  the structures involved, and how they fit together.

Consider the polynomial ring $R=\mathbf F_2[X]$ where $\mathbf F_2 = \{0,1\}$ with the usual field operations.
Now consider the polynomial $p(X) = X^4 + X^2 + 1$.
$P$ is irreducible, so we can construct the quotient ring $Q = R / (p(X))$

Now define $\alpha = \pi(X) \in Q$, which is a root of $p(x)$.
We can show (I think) that $$(\alpha^3 + 1)^2 = \alpha^6 + 1 = (\alpha^2+1) (\alpha^4 + \alpha^2 + 1) = 0$$
so therefore $\alpha^3 = 1$.

Similarly, we can check that $$ p(x) = \left[(x+\alpha)(x+\alpha^2)\right]^2$$ so all $\mathbf F_2[\alpha,\alpha^2]$ is the splitting field.

So, my question is, where does $\pi(X^3)$ fit into all this?
If
 $\alpha^3 = 1$, but $X^3$ is not congruent to $1$, does this mean that $\pi(X)^3 \ne \pi(X^3)$, and so the splitting field and the quotient ring are not isomorphic?  Because $2^4-1$ is not prime?

Comment: I haven't read your question closely, but did you notice that $X^4 + X^2 + 1 = (X^2 + X + 1)^2$? We only get a field when quotienting by an ideal generated by an irreducible polynomial, so you should probably use $X^2 + X + 1$ instead.

Comment: $p(x) \in \mathbb{F}_{2}[x]$ is $(x^{2}+x+1)^{2}$

Comment: Thank you! The structure falls apart because I believed $p(x)$ to be irreducible, and it very much isn't.  That all makes sense now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ was indeed irreducible, then $p$ would be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ which you contradicted.

It follows that $p$ is *reducible*, and you can check that indeed
$$p(x)=(x^2+x+1)^2\,. $$